# Angular4 "400 Bad Request" on POST Request with Object Containing Image

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

I am trying to save an object by passing it from Typescript (Angular 4) to the web api for processing. I have an image in the object. But it throws a 400 bad request each time it hits the **Create** service that should connect to the web api. I have searched the internet for days but all I found not only didn't have the solution that works but it is different in that, they try to upload a file alone and not a file in an object (Json object). Below is what I have tried so far.

In the HTML form, I have a file control with which I select the image to save

```
<input #imageInput type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onImageChange()" />
```

**TypeScript**

```
@ViewChild('imageInput') imageInput;

onImageChange() {
    let imgInput = this.imageInput.nativeElement;
    if (imgInput.files && imgInput.files[0]) {
      this.file = imgInput.files[0];
    }
  }

save(): void {
    this.saving = true;
    this.tax.branchId = this.appSession.user.branchId;
    this.tax.scanImage = this.file;
    console.log(this.file);
    this._taxService.create(this.tax)
        .finally(() => { this.saving = false; })
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.notify.success(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'), 'Tax Saved');
            this.close();
            this.modalSave.emit(null);
        });
  }
```

**Create Service (TypeScript)**

```
create(input: CreateTaxMapDto): Observable<TaxDto> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + '/api/services/app/Tax/SaveTax';

        const content_ = JSON.stringify(input ? input.toJS() : null);

        return this.http.request(url_, {
            body: content_,
            method: 'post',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            })
        });
    }
```

Where `content_` is:

```
{
    "taxTypeId": "4",
    "taxTypeName": null,
    "branchId": null,
    "branchN‌​ame": null,
    "dateOfReceipt": "2017-11-17",
    "amount": 23423434,
    "taxAuthorityId": "1",
    "taxAuthorityName": nul‌​l,
    "remark": null,
    "scanImage": {}
}
```

When it hits the **create** service, it throws the 400 bad request error. The Details of the error as follows;

```
> {code: 0, message: "Your request is not valid!", details: "The
> following errors were detected during validation. ↵ -  ↵",
> validationErrors: Array(1)} code : 0 details : "The following errors
> were detected during validation. ↵ -  ↵" message : "Your request is
> not valid!" validationErrors : Array(1) 0 : members : ["scanImage"]
> message : ""
> __proto__ : Object length : 1
> __proto__ : Array(0)
> __proto__ : Object
```

From the above error, **ScanImage** is the problem. How do I fix this please?

Comment: "When it hits the create service, it throws the 400 bad request error" We need one more thing: information about _what the API expects_ because that's where the problem lies. What is a `ScanImage` error? It looks like a [SANE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE) service?

Comment: @msanford It doesn't even get to the web api. I put a breakpoint on it and it doesn't hit. The error is thrown on client when it executes the service. However, if you must know the API expects an object which is what is passed into the create method in the service.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification (I misunderstood 'service', as it's unusual for an Angular service to return a status code like this). I only imagine the problem lies in `input.toJS()`, which I've not yet encountered and can't find a reference to. What does `content_` look like once it's set?

Comment: @msanford, Thanks for your attention. I logged `content_` in the console and it gave this: `{"taxTypeId":"4","taxTypeName":null,"branchId":null,"branchName":null,"dateOfReceipt":"2017-11-17","amount":23423434,"taxAuthorityId":"1","taxAuthorityName":null,"remark":null,"scanImage":{}}`. As you can see, `scanImage` is empty even though I selected an image in the file input control.